# How to bring a div in front of a fullscreen flash

Tags: flash, html

Is it possible to bring a div in front of a flash movie that is in full screen?

How can I do this if it's possible? I want to make a little box in my site and put some links in it and position it on top of a flash movie that is playing in my site so the user can have shortcuts there.

I don't want to put the links inside the flash animation :D

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just put the links directly in your flash? And yes you can overlay a div all depends on how you embed your flash

Comment: Well I don't want to put the links in the flash because I want to use youtube flash too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it. Make sure when embedding the swf you set wmode to transparent, here's a one page example for you. The overFlash div will appear over the movie. Hope this helps!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        #overFlash{padding:20px;background-color:#D9D9D9;width:150px;position:absolute;left:300px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overFlash">
            OVER FLASH!
        </div>

        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="test" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="550" height="400">
                    <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah crap - I didn't read your full question about the full screen. Sorry, this won't help you. And from what I know, you can't actually use HTML is full screen since you're not dealing with the browser at that point...

Comment: Ha, I missed the full screen think also. So the answer is no you can not overlay a div in full screen mode. There is no html present in full screen mode. You might want to study the youtube api to see if there is something you can use.

Comment: OK,  thank you guys anyway I knew that I have little chances to make this done by html :) but at least I've tryed :). I will give the answer to onekidney because maybe helps somebody else ...